# Silverlight and a form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I wondering if a can make a form with silverlight like an HTML form and submit its data to a server to store them on a database.

Can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definately do this.  But you cannot talk to a server directly via Silverlight like you can with ASP.Net.  You have to use web services to achieve this.

There are a number of ways to do this:
1. Use **Web Services**  (Old ASMX;  This has security issues)
2. Use **WCF**  (For complex systems)
3. Use **ADO.Net Data Services** (This is probably the easiest and fastest way to achieve this) using ADO.Net Entity Framework.
4. Use **RIA Services** (In CTP now for Silverlight 3)

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at some videos over here:
http://silverlight.net/learn/videocat.aspx?cat=2#HDI2WebServices
basically, you build your data model with Linq (or some other orm), expose that data through Select/Update/Delete/... methods with web service (new WCF or old one, ASMX), and consume that in silverlight. Silverlight automatically make proxy classes for communication. In Silverlight, you can use it's rich databinding capabilities, so you do not need to worry about how data are transferred, serialized, read from UI and similar.
Video tutorials on silverlight.net web explains most of stuff regarding programming SL2 really good.

Answer (score 1):

You can always host the sliverlight app in a web page which the forms app loads.

It may be possible to directly intergrate WPF and forms as well.

Answer (score 1):

Or you aren't running ASP.NET on the server like everybody always seems to assume you are and therefore don't use all these darned "Web Service" things, [you can just use `WebClient` and make your POST that way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197953(VS.95).aspx).

...I dont know why everybody thinks there is a need to layer on so many heaps of acronym goo between you and your webserver.  Your old javascript code wasn't interfacing with your backend using WCF, SOAP or whatever, why should Silverlight?  Keep it simple!  Silverlight is more than happy to make regular, old-fashioned, time-tested HTTP POST's.

And not to be shameless, I've been working on a library I use in my projects to make it easier to call your backend like you would have if you were using javascript: [WebBuddy](http://webbuddy.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an easy way to do make an html page in silverlight and fill it with data and post it to the server. it will use Silverlight browser interop to programmatically create an HTML  and set elements to it.

```
//Creates a blank html document
var htmldoc = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document;
// Returns a Reference type to the body of html page
var body = htmldoc.Body;

// Create a <form> element and add it to the body
var newForm = htmldoc.CreateElement("form");
newForm.SetAttribute("action", targetUrl);
newForm.SetAttribute("method", "post");
body.AppendChild(newForm);

//Add your elements to your form
HtmlElement input1 = htmldoc.CreateElement("input");
input1.SetAttribute("type", "hidden");
input1.SetAttribute("name", "someName");
input1.SetAttribute("value", "someValue");
newForm.AppendChild(input1);

//submit your form
newForm.Invoke("submit");
```

That Simple!

original Answer: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175910/navigate-and-post-data-from-silverlight)