# Submitting froms from silver light to asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, forms, submit

I'm newbie to silverlight , is it possible to submit a from from with in the silver light application . I want to use silverlight controls instaeda of asp.net , they look far better than asp.net controls .How to do this in silverlight 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you have got your answer by now, but for later readers, I found this way the best way to do this in Silverlight. this way you don't need any aspx pages and you can create and submit html pages directly from silverlight.

it will use Silverlight browser interop to programmatically create an HTML form and set elements to it.

```
//Creates a blank html document
var htmldoc = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document;
// Returns a Reference type to the body of html page
var body = htmldoc.Body;

// Create a <form> element and add it to the body
var newForm = htmldoc.CreateElement("form");
newForm.SetAttribute("action", targetUrl);
newForm.SetAttribute("method", "post");
body.AppendChild(newForm);

//Add your elements to your form
HtmlElement input1 = htmldoc.CreateElement("input");
input1.SetAttribute("type", "hidden");
input1.SetAttribute("name", "someName");
input1.SetAttribute("value", "someValue");
newForm.AppendChild(input1);

//submit your form
newForm.Invoke("submit");
```

That Simple!

original Answer: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175910/navigate-and-post-data-from-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

You can call form.submit() via a javascript function called from a silverlight control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

and you can also navigate: HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(url)