# Passing report parameters with POST, still hitting length limit

Tags: c#, silverlight, post, reporting-services

I have a Silverlight application (meant to be run in a browser) which allows the user to select as many SSRS (sub)reports as they like from a large list. The selected subreports get aggregated into one big report, and this report is launched in a new window.
Each subreport has its own set of parameters. As such, the parameter-value list can get very long. Previously, the application would use the GET method to pass parameter values, e.g.:

```
http://<serverName>/_vti_bin/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?http://<reportPath>&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Parameters=false&rc:Toolbar=true&rc:Zoom=100&FacilityUniqueValues=A&WorkWeek=0&...
```

But with long parameter-value lists, the URL could easily exceed 2000 characters. At around this length or greater, the report fails -- the browser just gives an HTTP 404 page. I figured this was due to a URL length limit somewhere along the line, so, after looking up solutions, I made it use the POST method to pass parameters, exactly as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9175975/908291). The URL above would now just look like:

```
http://<serverName>/_vti_bin/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?<reportPath>
```

However, the problem persists exactly as before when the parameter-value list is long.

I noticed that, when the list is shorter and the report is shown successfully, the browser redirects to a URL in the form:

```
http://<serverName>/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=<relativeReportPath>&rv%3aParamMode=Hidden&rv%3aZoom=100&rp%3aFacilityUniqueValues=A&rp%3aWorkWeek=0&...
```

i.e. The values are made into GET parameters anyway. I don't understand this, as I've seen many recommendations to use POST for getting around URL length limits when you have a lot of report parameters -- what's the point if it redirects to a GET URL?

So, is there a way to propagate the Posted parameters? Or another way around this problem?

I'm very inexperienced with most of the technologies involves, so I apologize for any relevant details I have not included -- please let me know what info may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reporting server you are connecting to is redirecting to a page and specifying the subreports as URL arguments. This is an issue in the reporting server and is not something you can fix in the Silverlight application.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I do have access to the reporting server, so I'd be willing to consider a solution from that end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regardless of whether it is POST or GET, by passing parameter via the uri, it's called URI tunneling, which has a predefined length limit (I think about 2000 characters if I remember correctly), therefore you will see no difference whether or not you use POST or GET. AKA.. http://url.com**?** <-- Anything after the **?** is Uri tunneling.

POST requests are usually accompanied by a BODY content (Can be XML, JSON, etc...), which is what I think your link to [navigate and post data from silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175910/navigate-and-post-data-from-silverlight/9175975#9175975) meant.  Body content/payload won't have the limitation of the URI string max length.  Body content will have a url http://url.com and an invisible payload until you inspect the message body of the request object using tools like Fiddler or your browser's developer's tool.  Notice the commented out part

```
// TODO: doc.CreateElement("input");
// TODO: SetAttribute("type", "hidden");
// TODO: SetAttribute("name", someName);
// TODO: SetAttribute("value", someValue);
// TODO: newForm.AppendChild()
```

That will set the value of the parameter to pass via the forms post request.  In the code above,   doc.CreateElement("input"); creates an input element to hold a hidden value of  "someValue" and name of "someName";

Some examples based on your querystring I can give you

```
doc.CreateElement("input");
SetAttribute("type", "hidden");
SetAttribute("name", "FacilityUniqueValues");
SetAttribute("value", "A");
newForm.AppendChild()

doc.CreateElement("input");
SetAttribute("type", "hidden");
SetAttribute("name", "WorkWeek");
SetAttribute("value", 0);
newForm.AppendChild()
```

So in conclusion, your server must be able to handle deconstruction of the form's parameters FacilityUniqueValues and WorkWeek.